# iOS: Some files don't open

Tags: ios

I am attempting to load image files as an NSString, but all of them come up `nil` using this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name.data()] ofType:nil];

NSString *da = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I am able to load many files, but all JPEG and PNG files fail for some reason. I thought it might have something to do with encoding so I switched it to usedEncoding, but it still didn't work.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I have been making an iOS/Android cross platform OpenGL graphics library in C++. Everything works except texture loading. Any file loading from disk goes through one function that is abstracted between systems. I need the image file in an STL string, so that I can pass it to an image parsing library to get the raw pixel data.

I just think that it's reduculous that the function I have can open any file except images.

Comment: Sorry, wrong one. `NSLog(da)` outputs `(null)`.

Comment: Why do you want to open an image as a string? The raw bytes in a JPEG, for example, are unlikely to be useful because they represent a pretty complex encoding scheme. Improve your question by giving us some idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code, passing an `NSError` instance instead of `nil`,

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                error:&error];
```

you will see that `stringWithContentsOfFile` cannot open the image file, returning `nil` and the error given is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)"...

Cocoa error 261 is `NSFileReadInapplicableStringEncodingError` which means the encoding of the file is different from the one you are passing (`NSUTF8StringEncoding`). But I have tried with the other encodings, and none works for PNG files.

You can still achieve what you want by loading the file as a `UIImage` and then converting the `UIImage` into a Base64 string.

- Since **iOS 7**, this is easier because you can **use the built in method `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`**:

  ```
  // Load the image and convert it to NSData
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];    
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  // You can use the equivalent UIImageJPEGRepresentation() for JPEG images

  // Convert NSData to a Base64 NSString
  NSString *base64ImageString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
  ```
- Previous to **iOS 7**, you can do the exact same thing but you will have to **implement your own Base64 encoding method** (Or import any of the many already available, eg. [nicklockwood/Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)).

Comment: I want to use just one function to load files, and I ultimately want a normal base 8 string for use in C/C++.

Comment: You can encapsulate this into a single method, but the only 2 options are either to do it like this, treating images separately from any other type of file, or to do it directly in C/C++ (which I am not sure how).

Comment: Not really, I just want to be able to load image files like I would any other file.

Comment: Updated answer with a bit more of context after research.